# "... a constant companion and housekeeper in his sister." What does the "in" mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I'm reading Jane Austen's novel of "Sense and Sensibility". There is coming a sentence as below:

> The late owner of this estate was a single man, who lived to a very advanced age, and who for many years of his life, had a constant companion and housekeeper **in his sister**.

In which, the sentence, of "had a constant companion and housekeeper in his sister." I have two questions:

1. What does the sentence "[he] had a constant companion and housekeeper in his sister" mean?
2. What does the word "in" of "**in** his sister" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"had a constant companion and housekeeper in his sister" implies that the late owner had a sister who gave him company as well as took care of the house.

The "**in**" represents "in the form of" i.e. the multiple traits of the sister e.g.:

*"The late owner of this estate was a single man, who lived to a very advanced age, and who for many years of his life, had a companion and a housekeeper in the form of his sister"*

Comment: In the way, shape, or form of means under the circumstances or conditions of, which I imply. Thanks for your answer.